# Clearing Paramiko ChannelFile

Tags: python, paramiko

I have the following code for reading input from a channel in my SSH server:

```
f = chan2.makefile("rU")
command = f.read(1)
f.close()

#some code here. 
#client presses more keys here.

f = chan2.makefile("rU")
command = f.read(1)
f.close()
```

I can use this code in order to get a single char from the client. But if the user presses buttons between two parts, I want to ignore them. I was thinking about emptying the ChannelFile before each execution of `f.read(1)` but I couldn't find a way. Is there a way for this?